# validate time GMT offset and striping with regex?

Tags: php, regex, time, timezone, gmt

```
// create a string
$string = '+7';

// try to match the beginning of the string
if(preg_match("{-15 to +12}", $string))
    {
    // if it matches we echo this line
    return {strip all the + sign}
    echo 'its a valid gmt time';
    }
else
    {
    echo 'not valid gmt time';
    }
```

Question:

1. please see the first {} on preg_match, is how can we do that ? im new on regex and i just dont know where to start
2. on the second {} can we somehow strip the + sign by useing regex ?
3. is the gmt range is right ? -14 to +12 ( well thats what i see on http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php )

Thanks

Comment: What is the format you are expecting?

Comment: Must you use regexp? Is the `+` sign required?

Comment: @Aircule what do you mean by format ? sorry newbie :| . @kennttm is there a better solution without regexp ?

Comment: Is this code even working? coz i see some error in this line - {strip all the + sign}

Comment: @user What's the `$string` supposed to be so it's valid?

Comment: @shubham no, @aircule ive update my question, thanks for asking it.

Comment: **Note:** PHP's `Etc/...` timezones use the opposite sign as is standard and are primarily used for legacy purposes.  The valid range of offsets should be from UTC–12 (in the west) to UTC+14 (in the east).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function validGMT($input)
{
    $gmt = '/^(?:\+?(?:[0]?[0-9]|[1][0-2])|-(?:[0][0-9]|[1][0-4]))$/';
    if ( preg_match( $gmt, $input ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }       
}
```

edit*

ive just notice that if you are at php5.2.
do this

```
$val='-2';
$options['options']['min_range'] = -14;
$options['options']['max_range'] = 12; 
$var1 = filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,$options);
var_dump($var1);
```

Comment: `[0]` can be expressed with just `0`.

Comment: Gumbo can you explain it more ? +1

Comment: `[…]` means *one of the characters expressed with `…`*. Now if “`…`” is just a single character like in this case `0`, it is more comprehensive to just write `0` instead of `[0]`.

Comment: example ? btw @adam ive just notice that 44 works too, please check again :|

Comment: ok ive edit it. use that instead. but it have to be a 01 not an 1, still cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = '+7';
if (in_array($string, range(-15, 12))) {
    echo 'its a valid gmt time';
} else {
    echo 'not valid gmt time';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

1. //match 0-15 with a +,- in front.

   ```
   if(preg_match("/(+|-)([0-9]|1[1-5])/", $string)){
         //match process here 
   }
   ```

That would match your -15,+12 I would imagine.

2. To strip out all the {+} signs.

   //take out + and replace with + 
   $newString = str_replace(array("+"),"", $oldString);

Answer (score 0):

The regexp could be:

```
/\+?[0-9]|\+?1[0-2]|\-[1-9]|\-1[0-5]/
```

This would match 0..12, +0..+12, -1..-15
If the + sign is required, use the RegExp without the ?.

then just do a str_replace on the number:

```
$number = str_relace('+', '', $number);
```

Comment: btw it doesnt return true if 10 11 or +10 +11 , -10 -11 ( two decimals. ) im trying it on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 0):

I would do :

```
preg_match("/^([+-]\d+)/", $string, $m);
if(isset($m[1]) && $m[1] > -16 && $m[1] < 13) {
    echo 'its a valid gmt time';
} else {
    echo 'not valid gmt time';
}
```

Comment: hmm dont know but it does give me an Undefined offset: 1 on line 2